# On parsing datetime, ValueError: time data does not match format

Tags: python, datetime

I have date time in the format `YYYY/DOY/HHMM`

DOY = Day of year

I tried to parse as follows.

```
from datetime import datetime
s = "1929/189/1820"
res = datetime.strptime(s, "%y/%j/%H%M")
print (res)
```

ValueError: time data '2029/199/1820' does not match format '%y/%j/%H%M'.

Comment: You would learn much more if you tried to fix it yourself. Asking for help immediately after every error will not make you a better programmer. Coding is hard, yes. Blood, tears and sweat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Y for year should be capitalized.

This should fix it.

`datetime.strptime(s, "%Y/%j/%H%M")`